# Log in to GitHub through SourceTree no longer works when repository settings were changed

Tags: sourcetree

I'm getting an error in SourceTree when I try to login after making some changes to the repository.

I've updated the information in the Remote Repository settings dialog path but when I run a commit it shows the old information.

I've also tried restarting and the new info shows in the dialog after a restart.

It looked like SourceTree might be storing some old information somewhere but could very well be something else I still need to do.

Answer (score 0):

SourceTree was storing old information for my repository and even when I updated it in the Remote repository paths dialog it would not push my changes indicating incorrect info.

I found that if I put the user name in the repository URL it works.

Before:

```
https://github.com/username/repository.git
```

After:

```
https://username@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Note I added `username@` to the URL where `username` is your GitHub username.